# Best way to find & replace across an entire WordPress website?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using a theme purchased from ThemeForest & need to change a default color from red (#FC2820) to orange (#FF8C27) across the whole site. I've already tried to edit the CSS sheets, add important tags, etc. but it's not working & the default is overwriting the edits.

I want to replace all instances of #FC2820 with #FF8C27, across the whole site.

Would a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/ work well?

If there's a better way, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's always possible to overwrite CSS.  Find and Replace will work in the theme database, whereas the colors are most likely in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual studio Code (for example) and Ctrl+shift+F to find all occurences in all files.

And maybe check into the database as well if there is an occurence of #FC2820